# Animated marker with Mapbox GL JS

Tags: javascript, animation, marker, mapbox-gl-js

I would like to animate (having an animated gif, or a png sequence) a marker with mapbox gl js.

Does anyone has any link/doc/ressource talking about it? I can't find nothing but marker animation along lines.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Perhaps you could use a video instead of an animated marker. https://www.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/api/#videosource

Comment: are you just adding a gif into a marker? - i.e. using an image tag to render the gif file? -

Answer (score 3):

Sure, you can use this [example](https://www.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/example/custom-marker-icons/) and create its variations based on your needs.

For example, use following code to display gif marker:

```js
mapboxgl.accessToken = '<api key>';
var map = new mapboxgl.Map({
  container: 'map',
  style: 'mapbox://styles/mapbox/streets-v9',
  center: [-74.50, 40],
  zoom: 9
});

function addeMarkerToMap(map, coordinates) {
  // create a DOM element for the marker
  var el = document.createElement('div');
  el.className = 'marker';

  // add marker to map
  new mapboxgl.Marker(el)
    .setLngLat(coordinates)
    .addTo(map);
}

addeMarkerToMap(map, [-74.5, 40]);
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

#map {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
}

.marker {
  background-image: url(https://media.giphy.com/media/Bfa45K0r6cCIw/giphy.gif);
  width: 32px;
  height: 32px;
}
```

```html
<script src='https://api.tiles.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/v0.51.0/mapbox-gl.js'></script>
<link href='https://api.tiles.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/v0.51.0/mapbox-gl.css' rel='stylesheet' />

<div id='map' class="myMap"></div>
```

PS: Replace `<api key>` with your actual API key to run the example code without authorization warning.

Comment: Is there a more performant solution than a html dom element? I assume this will slow down a lot if it exceeds >100 marker

Comment: @nauti I will have to dig bit dipper in the docs to findout, but you can get performance gain by moving style from javascript to css and just adding class to the appended div tag.

Comment: @nauti Check my updated code and use it when you create a new marker. I couldn't find anything else inside documentation. Creating new element with a new marker won't be that much of a performance hit.

Comment: Nice example ! However, the image doesn't really point the given lat/lng. How can you change the anchor if you want the center/bottom of your marker to point out the location?